# Call multiple times get_global_id() vs save the result in the local variable?

Tags: cuda, opencl

It is probably a silly question, but:
How expensive is it to call some `get_*` function in OpenCL-kernels? Is it better to save the result for future usage in some local varialbe or to call the desired function whenever it needed?

Or it is platform dependent?

PS
I think, cuda solves it better with various threadIdx variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should be free for all GPU architectures. It should be replaced by a corresponding hardware register or a constant in a cache bank.

Compiler could also do constant propagation on it. You can check yourself using AMD *Stream Analyser*:

### OpenCL:

```
__kernel 
void testKernel(__global uint * uintArray)
{
    uint threadId = get_global_id(0);

    uintArray[threadId] = 0xbaadf00d;
}
```

### Radeon HD 5870 (Cypress) assembly:

```
0 ALU: ADDR(32) CNT(10) KCACHE0(CB0:0-15) KCACHE1(CB1:0-15) 
      0  x: MOV         R1.x,  (0xBAADF00D, -0.001327039325f).x      
         t: MULLO_INT   ____,  R1.x,  KC0[1].x      
      1  x: ADD_INT     ____,  R0.x,  PS0      
      2  w: ADD_INT     ____,  PV1.x,  KC0[6].x      
      3  z: LSHL        ____,  PV2.w,  (0x00000002, 2.802596929e-45f).x      
      4  y: ADD_INT     ____,  KC1[0].x,  PV3.z      
      5  x: LSHR        R0.x,  PV4.y,  (0x00000002, 2.802596929e-45f).x      
01 MEM_RAT_CACHELESS_STORE_RAW: RAT(1)[R0].x___, R1,  VPM
```

Here `get_global_id(0)` maps to constant cache bank value `KC0[1].x`.
So, for answering your question I would use the most readable form.